# How to add css class to Action link in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, actionlink

I am creating `MVC5` project.using `Inspina theme` I have using `Entity framework`  its generated Code Like this  `Edit delete details`

Following Like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ClientId })  |
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ClientId }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ClientId })
```

Previous added custom font icon edit  button and delete class like this

```
 <a class="fa fa-edit">@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ClientId })</a>
 <a class="fa fa-times">@Url.Action("Delete", new { id=item.ClientId })</a>
```

Finally I want `fa fa-edit`  this class inside to action link code Entity framework Generator. How can I add looks like my previous button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add class to `ActionLink` like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ClientId }, new { @class = "fa fa-edit" }) 
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ClientId }, new { @class = "fa fa-times" })
```

Comment: You don´t need to add two different instances, you can do @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ClientId, @class = "fa fa-edit" }

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ClientId }, new { @class = "myCssClass" })
```

The `@` is important because `class` is a C# keyword.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You don´t need to add two different instances, you can do         @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ClientId, @class = "fa fa-edit" }

Comment: One is for MVC routing parameters and the other for HTML attributes.

Answer (score 2):

You can set it via htmlAttributes parameter of ActionLink MVC helper method like below, you should use **@class** property for your htmlAttributes object.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ClientId, @class="MyClass" })  |
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ClientId, @class="MyClass"  }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ClientId, @class="MyClass"  })
```

Hope this helps